# Table with multiple columns vs one with JSON to save all in one?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a lot of doubts about what can be better in performance and speed..

What would be better with about 50k posts?

Option 1 - Table:

```
id -- note_1 -- note1_color -- note_2 -- note_2_color -- .. (up to 5)
1  --   3.5  --    red      --   6    --    green
```

Option 2 - Table (The same that above but without colors)

```
id -- note_1 -- note_2 -- note_3 .. (up to 5)
1  --   3.5  --   6   --   9
```

but I need call my function to calc the colors for all notes any time visitor enter the post

Option 3 - Table:

```
id -- notes (type text)
1  --  {"note_1":3.5,"note_1_color":"red" ... }
```

and then use json_decote to convert and print in PHP.
Thanks you

Comment: What happens if you have 7 notes?

Comment: nothing, I only ask me what is better